# Send complex json object to Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send a complex object to ajax controller for spring mvc search engine, with 3 variables: the current page, items per page and the search parameters. The problem is that with the declaration of the controller method does not take me the params variable as a Map.

As I can send the structure to collect on the controller 3 variables separately?

Error:

> Required Map parameter 'params' is not present

```
  var dataToSend = {
        'page': 1,
        'itemsPerPage': 10,
        'params': {
          'codItem': "10",
          'nameItem': "foo"
        }
      };  

      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
      }).success(function(data) {
        callback(data);
      });        




 public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> search(@RequestParam(value="params") Map<String, String> params, @RequestParam(value = "page") int page, @RequestParam(value = "itemsPerPage") int itemsPerPage){
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this properly you need to use JSON library. Spring is bundled with Jackson.

First you need to create class to represent your JSON.

```
public class MyJson {
  int page;
  int itemsPerPage;
  Map<String, String> params;

  public MyJson() {}

  ... getters/setters

}
```

You need to change $.ajax, send data like this { data : JSON.stringify(dataToSend)}, becouse parameter need, a name.

In your controller method write this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// readValue(youStringJson, destinactionClass)
MyJson json = mapper.readValue(data, MyJson.class);
```

If you have getter for MyJson params field you can iterate over json.getParams() map.

Comment: you don't need a wrapper..you can simply say Map<String,Object> json= mapper.readValue(YOURMAP , Map.class);

Answer (score 1):

```
/* An Alternative Solution: See if this helps::::Sample Code of java,javascript,jsp for search parameters. Search Parameter POJO will have search parameters + Pagenumber + RecordCounton the page + sortColumn in it */

    public class SearchParameters implements Serializable{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4847934022647742263L;
        private Integer pageNumber;
        private String sortColumn;
        private Integer recordCount;
        private String sortOrder;
        private Long gdsProductId; // some search parameter
        private Integer ruleId; // some search parameter

    //getter and setters

    }
/* your java controller method, which accepts the SearchParameter Object */

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, GDS> search(SearchParameters parameters)
        throws Exception {
     // Print Parameter 
     logger.info("read :=" + parameters);
     // your logic to be written here
}

/* Your Javascript will have the below function.
   $("#searchPaginationform").serialize() will send the data for all the hidden elements of searchPaginationform in the below jsp.
  form  searchPaginationform will have hidden fields for the pagenumer,rows and other       elements */

    $.post('search.form', $("#searchPaginationform").serialize(), function (response) {

    }
/* Your Jsp -- see the hiddenfield name is matching the SearchParameter instance variable -*/

    <form:form id="searchPaginationform">
        <input type="hidden" name="gdsProductId" id="gdsProductId" >
        <input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" id="pageNumber" value=1>
        <input type="hidden" name="sortColumn" id="sortColumn" value="metamap_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="recordCount" id="recordCount" value=10>
        <input type="hidden" name="sortOrder" id="sortOrder" value="desc">
        <input type="hidden" name="ruleId" id="ruleId"> 
    </form:form>
```

Comment: My problem is I want to send variables itemsPerPage page and separate params for later search process, which has already put me with them as follows:

          $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize () + "&page =" + 1 + "&itemsPerPage =" + 10,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
          }).success(function(data) {
            callback(data);
          }); 
But as I have the page and within the params itemsPerPage Variable

Comment: You can use IE9 , dev tools(F12) and capture the request(by clicking Nework tab and Click 'Start Capturing' button.Looks like HTTP request doesn't have the parameter named 'Params' in your case.

Comment: May be your ajax call might be passing params in request body. try @RequestBody in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply inject the `HttpServletRequest` into your Controller method and read the body yourself as shown below :

```
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> search(HttpServletRequest request)
{

    String params;
    try 
    {
        params = IOUtils.toString( request.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(params);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   //Your return statement.
}
```

OutPut : `{"page":1,"itemsPerPage":10,"params":{"codItem":"10","nameItem":"foo"}}`

You can read this attributes by converting this string into JSON Object by using JSON API sunch as [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Or create POJO that contain all your attributes define in JSON and convert your Json strig directly to POJO object.

Sample Code :

```
MyClass obj = new Gson().fromJson(params, MyClass.class);
```

May this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem as follows:

```
public class SearchRequestDto {

  private String page;

  private String itemsPerPage;

  private MultiValueMap<String, List<String>> params;

  }

@ResponseBody
public HashMap<String, Object> buscador(SearchRequestDto searchRequest)
{
}
```

The problem is that it works for the structure of the example, if I try to pick up the form parameters, sends me not as a json:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr("action"),
    type: 'POST',
    data: {  
      'params': form.serialize(),
      'page': start,
      'itemsPerPage': end  
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false
  }).success(function(data) {
    callback(data);
  });
```

Result:

```
itemsPerPage 5
page 1
params codItem=asdfasdf&namItem=asdfasdfasdf&tipItem=1000600&tipItem=1000492&public=on&private=on&provinceItem=15&munItem=262&munItem=270&munItem=276&capItem=123123
```

And serializeArray():

itemsPerPage 5
page 1

```
params [10] [name] munItem
params [10] [value] 270
params [11] [name] munItem
params [11] [value] 276
params [13] [name] capItem
params [13] [value] 123123
params [2] [name] codItem
params [2] [value] asdfasdf
params [3] [name] nameItem
params [3] [value] asdfasdfasdf
params [4] [name] tipItem
params [4] [value] 1000600
params [5] [name] tipItem
params [5] [value] 1000492
params [6] [name] public
params [6] [value] on
params [7] [name] private
params [7] [value] on
params [8] [name] provinceItem
params [8] [value] 15
params [9] [name] munItem
params [9] [value] 262
```

As I can send it as in the structure of dataToSend? the only way is to go through the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

My enviroment:
AngularJs, SpringMVC, Gson jsonobject

Usually if i send a complex json object from font end to back end, i will do a generic way like below to handle it.

first:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: contextPath+"/voice/submitWrapupForm",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $.param({
              content : angular.toJson( { array:$(form).serializeArray() })
          }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' }
).success(function (data, status) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

i use angularJs to submit a formatted json string, i believe using jquery ajax will be the same, just need to be sure that data u sent is json formatted string.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

second:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitForm", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody String submitForm(String content) {
    JsonObject j = new Gson().fromJson(content ,JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();
    return j.toString();
}
```

u can watch the json content is pass to mvc controller, and in controller u can use Gson to convert and to json object.