# How to pass List<String> in post method using Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I need to pass a list of values in the request body of `POST` method but I get `400: Bad Request error`.

Below is my sample code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveFruits", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResultObject saveFruits(@RequestBody List<String> fruits) {
    ...
}
```

The JSON I am using is: `{"fruits":["apple","orange"]}`

Comment: Did you close the quote after orange or is it a typo here on stack? `{"fruits":["apple","orange"]}`

Comment: yes I did. It was just my sample code copy paste error. Bad request error still exists

Comment: Perhaps this could hep you http://stackoverflow.com/a/25523151/1793718

Comment: For given json how about using `Map<String, List<String>>` instead of List<String> in @RequestBody no extra wrapper class would be required than.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You are using wrong JSON. In this case you should use JSON that looks like this:

```
["orange", "apple"]
```

If you have to accept JSON in that form :

```
{"fruits":["apple","orange"]}
```

You'll have to create wrapper object:

```
public class FruitWrapper{

    List<String> fruits;

    //getter
    //setter
}
```

and then your controller method should look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveFruits", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResultObject saveFruits(@RequestBody FruitWrapper fruits){
...
}
```

Comment: Correct answer. You can easily determine what might be expected by doing the process in reverse i.e. writing a method which returns the JSON representation of a list returns ["orange", "apple"] as noted above.

Comment: When I tried List<String> objects; is wasnt working, I had content type error, I used ArrayList<String> in my wrapper and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 5):

I had the same use case,
You can change your method defination in the following way :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveFruits", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResultObject saveFruits(@RequestBody Map<String,List<String>> fruits) {
    ..
}
```

**The only problem is it accepts any key in place of "fruits" but You can easily get rid of a wrapper if it is not big functionality.**

Answer (score 4):

You can pass input as `["apple","orange"]`if you want to leave the method as it is.

It worked for me with a similar method signature.