# Json List to String List : Spring mvc Controller

Tags: json, spring, http, spring-mvc, post

I want to send this List example :

```
{"id":[1]}
```

To this controller :

```
public String addUsersToProject(@RequestBody List<String> usersIds, @PathVariable String projectTitle){..}
```

But I can't read the list :

```
Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Do you use jackson?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789357/how-to-pass-liststring-in-post-method-using-spring-mvc this question already has an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is create wrapper class with id field as List (userIds).

Example:

```
class IdsWrapper {
    private List<Integer> id;
}
```

And use it in controller:

```
public String addUsersToProject(@RequestBody IdsWrapper ids) {...}
```

Also you can check link [Possible maping solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441557/rest-with-spring-and-jackson-full-data-binding)