# how to call the spring boot rest api controller which will receive list of strings

Tags: spring-boot

written the spring boot rest api controller like this.

calling below api like this http://localhost:8080/api/foos?numbers=1&numbers=2 but getting 404 error.(type=Not Found, status=404).

```
 @Controller
    public class ExController {
    
        @GetMapping( "/api/foos")
        @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Boolean> findTypes(@RequestParam List<String> numbers) {
    Map<String, Boolean> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println("...................");

return  itemMap;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789357/how-to-pass-liststring-in-post-method-using-spring-mvc/34789985

Comment: its not my post.he is asking POST.here I am getting error in GET mapping.

Comment: referred this url but no use in my case .. https://medium.com/@AADota/spring-passing-list-and-array-of-values-as-url-parameters-1ed9bbdf0cb2

Comment: The way you submit query parameters for the annotated `@RequestParam` argument is correct. I believe there is another issue with your setup that is not related to how you implemented the controller.